# Getting mixing apples and oranges error while inheriting res.users

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to inherit res.users in odoo 12. But I am getting mixing apples and oranges error. I want to create a new table having the fields of res.users models.

model.py

```
class SaleIndividual(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.individual'
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    individual_description = fields.Char()
```

view.xml

```
<odoo>
  <record id="view_form_sale_custom_individual" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Individual Form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.individual</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="auth_signup.res_users_view_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="login" position="after">
          <field name="individual_description" />
            </field>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

error:

```
raise TypeError("Mixing apples and oranges: %s in %s" % (item, self))
TypeError: Mixing apples and oranges: sale.individual(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x123018048>,) in res.users()
```

Answer (score 0):

First Method:

If you want t inherit res users then please follow the below steps:

```
class ResUsers(models.Model):
 _inherit = 'res.users'
individual_description = fields.Char()
```

view.xml

```
<odoo>
<record id="view_form_sale_custom_individual" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">Individual Form</field>
<field name="model">res.users</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="auth_signup.res_users_view_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="login" position="after">
      <field name="individual_description" />
        </field>
</field>
```

Second Method:

if you want create new model then follow the steps below:

```
class SaleIndividual(models.Model):
 _name = 'sale.individual'
 _inherit = 'res.users'
individual_description = fields.Char()
```

Need to create a new view file with out inheriting res users view file for this case.

```
<odoo>
<record id="view_form_sale_custom_individual" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">Individual Form</field>
<field name="model">sale.individual</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
       <field name="individual_description" />
    </form>
</field>
```

Comment: my question regarding the second method is that how to create sale.individual inheriting res.users?

Comment: for that you have to create a new view file for sale.individual model

Comment: That is only problem I am facing while creating sale.individual.
The above code that I have sent is the code I wrote for creating sale.individual model and getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: @ShilpaGhosh I think you have to uninstall the module and check by installing it once again,  Because when i tried your same code , it worked without any issue.(I can't upload the screen shot in comments, otherwise will give the image.)